# VNStat Incorrect Usage Stats

Tags: 14.04, networking, vnstat

I'm trying to monitor total bandwidth usage of a month's period and kill a process if it exceed a certain threshold.

It seemed to be OK last month however when i run the below, it shows my usage as around 60GB, when i check my VPS provider it's showing more like 2.2TB, which i believe as i can see the copies it has made, has in fact copied at least 1.5TB.

Has anyone else seen this with vnstat, or does anyone have any better ideas for me to monitor the usage, fairly lightweight.

Is there anyway to manually update the vnstat DB with the status it's missing, so for this month i can manually update to figures that match my VPS provider?

```
vnstat -u
vnstat --oneline | awk -F";" {'print $9":"$10":"$11'}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't `vnstat -m` show you what you need, per month?

Comment: `vnstat -m` shows the same values as the command i'm using, so i'm afraid not.